# Apply ripple effect for specified element of a shape

Tags: android

I have a view with the following background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

My problem is when I press the view, ripple effect applies to the whole of the view. So unpressed and pressed states of view look like:

[image: Unpressed view]
[image: Pressed view]

So I want to apply ripple effect only for `<solid/>` tag of the shape, to have `<solid/>` with `holo_orange_dark` color and `<stroke/>` with `#ffffff` color in the pressed state.
How can I do this?